# Excel Advanced Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel

On the “Inventory” worksheet, apply formatting to the rows of data that bolds the text and changes to text color to RGB “0”, “176”, “80” if the number “Sold Last Month” is more than 90% of the number “In Stock”.

[database-inventoryWorksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX8QL.png)

Comment: Hi ItiDubai, I see that you are new to the community. Conditional formatting is difficult to troubleshoot in this forum. Based on the information provided, it sounds like you are getting unexpected behavior from conditional formatting. Could you edit your question to include the exact conditional logic and the behavior you expect? Screenshots may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula you need.

```
=SoldLastMonth>(InStock*0.9)
```

It's tested to work with two named ranges "SoldLastMonth" and "InStock" because those are the names you provided. In your worksheet they might actually be cells. The actual formula you might use therefore might look more like the one below.

```
=$D2>($G2*.9)
```

To apply this formula to CF, select the entire range you wish to format, then enter the formula for the first row of the selected range (row 2 in my example).

After entering the formula you can select the format you want, for example Bold and coloured. You will be able to select the colour from the pallet. No need (and no chance) to specify RGB. For more information about conditional formatting please read up on the subject online. Such tuition isn't provided here.